# Are there reliability issues with Hondas i-DCD engines?

Tags: engine, honda

I am looking at purchasing a 2014 Honda Fit Hybrid imported from Japan.

There does not seem to be a lot of information on the reliability of this car, but I did see 1 article claiming expensive issues with this model engine.  Subsequent googling found statements about 3 recalls up to Feb 2014, but I'm confused if this was a hardware problem and if it affects models sold after February 2014?

Does anyone know how reliable these cars are?
Relatedly, when people talk about dct (dual clutch technology?) does this refer to the i-dcd engine?

Comment: You found **one** article and are worried about reliability... Perhaps if you had found 10,000...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Hondas are generally highly reliable, and as long as you take care of the car, odds are good that you'll be fine.

Comment: @SolarMike the problem us there was 1 article on iDCD engines but quite a few on dct engines, which I think may refer to iDCD as well. Also, there may not be a lot of reports because ive not seen a lot of these cars....